# android set button height

Tags: android, layout, button

i am having trouble in setting the button height, while the emulator is showing desirably (button being narrow), running on the phone device S2 (button become squares). How could I set properly such that the buttons would be appearing narrow as in the emulator?

I have set the button with textSize = 1dp and to wrap_content, then the emulator show properly reflecting this change as a very narrow button, yet running on S2 it still appears as a square.

Do anyone know how to run it sucessfully on actual devices? Many thanks!!!

### Emulator:

[image]

## Phone device:

[image]

### Layout codes:

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/colorBlackBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/colorWhiteBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/colorRedBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_btn" />

        // same for other buttons 

    </TableRow>
```